# Android Backend Starter setFilter

Tags: android, backend

I'm trying the new Android Mobile Backend. I did all the basic samples and now I want to set one or multiple filters. I tried only with one but the getCloudBackend().list returns a null list.

I have in the entity that I filter the parameter with the value. And if I remove the line where I filter, the service returns a list with data.

What I have to do if I want to filter by one parameter? and if I want to filter by the owner? and if I want to put more than one filter?

This is my code:

```
getCloudBackend().clearAllSubscription();
CloudQuery cq = new CloudQuery("MyEntity");
cq.setSort(CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT, Order.DESC);
cq.setLimit(100);
q.setFilter(F.eq("myparameter", "myvalue"));
cq.setScope(Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST);
getCloudBackend().list(cq, handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should post the error (or response) you get in the LogCat and also in the backend log. Filters are a bit tricky. I suggest you to check [`CloudQuery`](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/api_reference/cloudquery) documentation to see the filter limitations, and [`CloudEntity`](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/api_reference/cloudentity) to check the data you can send, retrieve and how.

About queries the documentation says:

> Queries in the Cloud Backend API have some restrictions that originate
>   from the App Engine Datastore. By default, App Engine automatically
>   creates an index for each user defined property (with the exception of
>   List/Map properties). This index supports the following forms of
>   queries: - Kind name specified, no filters, no sorting - Queries with
>   only equality filters (F.eq) on indexed properties with no sorting -
>   Queries with only inequality filters, such as F.lt, F.ge, on a single
>   indexed property - Queries with one sort order on one property with no
>   filters

For example, for `String` properties you can only check for equality (eq/ne). You can't mix equaltiy filters with inequality ones. i.e. :

```
F.and(F.eq(PROPERTY_NAME, "Manuel"), F.gt(PROPERTY_AGE, Integer.valueOf(18)));
```

Will give you an error `DatastoreNeedIndexException`.

The documentation also says:

> All other query forms will raise a DatastoreNeedIndexException on the
>   backend. To use a more complex form of queries, you need to add an
>   [Index Configuration](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Index_Configuration) on the backend.

To do such you need edit `datastore-indexes.xml` in your backend. In order to do that you can use the command `./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_indexes myapp/war`.

Looks promising though I haven't tested it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Filters are case-sensitive, in the Guestbook example:

1. `cq.setFilter(F.eq("MESSAGE","fabulous"));` -> This won't work... don't let Google Cloud Console fool you.
2. `cq.setFilter(F.eq("message","fabulous"));` -> This will work... don't know why is case sensitive.

Let me know if this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have to do if I want to filter by one parameter?

I think it is better to use `getCloudBackend().listByProperty()` method instead of `getCloudBackend().list()`

Example of this method usage:

```
getCloudBackend().listByProperty("yourKindName", "yourPropertyName", Op.EQ,
yourPropertyValueObject, null, 1, Scope.PAST, yourHandler);
```

> and if I want to filter by the owner?

You can use the listed above method. Just put your owner property name instead of `yourPropertyName`

> and if I want to put more than one filter?

To use multiple filter for one property I created `listByPropertyAnd()` method in `CloudBackendAsync` class:

```
    public void listByPropertyAnd(String kindName, String propertyName,
            CloudQuery.Order order, int limit, Scope scope,
            CloudCallbackHandler<List<CloudEntity>> handler, F... filters) {

        CloudQuery cq = new CloudQuery(kindName);
        cq.setFilter(F.and(filters));
        cq.setSort(propertyName, order);
        cq.setLimit(limit);
        cq.setScope(scope);
        this.list(cq, handler);
    }
```

Example of this method usage:

```
getCloudBackend().listByPropertyAnd("yourKindName", "yourKindName", Order.DESC,
                1000, Scope.FUTURE_AND_PAST, yourHandler,
                F.gt("yourKindName", yourFirstValue),
                F.lt("yourKindName", yourSecondValue), F.eq("date", mToday));
```

In this case you can use any number of filters for one property but it should be compliant with  [datastore indexing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) rules.
Also it might be useful to read this [Java Datastore Filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Filters) and this one [Mobile Backend Starter - API Guide](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference)