# Mobile backend starter datastore queries for multi-valued properties

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I've started implementing my own example with Mobile Backend Starter and cannot resolve one problem with queries.
According to the spec https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries there should be no difference making a query with filter for single or multi-valued property.

Unfortunately I can not make it work with an Android app example provided on Mobile Backend Starte page.

Here is the code I use to add multi-valued property:

```
newPost.put("tags", Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));
```

and a filter I use to get each record containing one of the specified properties:

```
CloudQuery query = new CloudQuery("Guestbook");

query.setFilter(F.eq("tags","two"));

getCloudBackend().list(query, handler);
```

As a result an empty list is always returned. If no filter is specified, all properties are returned from the backend as expected.

Is it possible to make queries for multi-valued properties with the current implementation?

Comment: This answer might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452334/2147383

Answer (score 0):

Multi-valued properties can be queried. You can utilise a filter predicate

```
Filter tagfilter = new FilterPredicate("tags",
                      FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                      "two");
query.setFilter(tagfilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer as far as I know about Mobile Backend Starter is no. Though I don't know about google-cloud-endpoints.

If I understand it right, you send a `CloudEntity` (`newPost`) with a property being a `List`. In the ["documentation" of mobile backend starter](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/api_reference/cloudentity) they say that one of the supported types for `CloudEntity` are:

> List/Map:
>
> java.util.List or java.util.Map object that can contain long strings
> (longer than 500 characters) and child List/Map. These elements are
> not indexed on Datastore and can not be used as a query
> filtering/sorting condition. Empty List/Maps are not stored on
> Datastore

So you **can not use that List/Map as a filter**.